# Pointcut for method with call of the specific method inside

Tags: aspectj

I have method A and method B. I want pointcut to be attached to the method A, only if method B is called in method A.
Is it possible with Aspets? Thank you. 
Example:
Aspect Code:

```
package aspects.unregistrator;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;

import com.core.Item;

public aspect Unregistrator {

pointcut unRegistrated() : within(tasks..*) && call(* find(..));

    after() : unRegistrated()  {
        Item.unregisterAll();
    }
}
```

this will attach point after every call of find() in every method in tasks package

but I need unregisterAll() to be executed after every method that contains find() call, like this:

```
package tasks.helpers;

public class TableHelper {

public static void clickButtonInCell(final WTable table) {
    table.find(SubitemFactory(Element.BUTTON)).click();
    Item.unregisterAll();
}
```

Comment: I think so, but this is StackOverflow. So please post code and do not ask such general, imprecise questions. Then you can describe what you want to achieve along the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found one way to make this possible using two special keywords of the AspectJ language: `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart` and `thisJoinPointStaticPart`. In this way, you need to keep the enclosing join points where the `find()` method being called (in your case `public static void clickButtonInCell(final WTable table)`). Then, you need to check each method execution whether the enclosing join point of the find() method is the same as its join point.

For example:

```
class TableHelper {

    public static void clickButtonInCell(final WTable table) {
        System.out.println("clickButtonInCell");
        table.find();  
        // Item.unregisterAll() will be called after find() 
    }

    public static void clickButtonInX(final WTable table) {
        System.out.println("clickButtonInX");
        table.doSomething(); 
        // even if Item.unregisterAll() is matched with this method execution, it will not work
    } 

}


public aspect Unregistrator {

    String enclosedJP = "";

    pointcut unRegistrated() : within(tasks..*) && call(* find(..));

    after() : unRegistrated()  {
        enclosedJP = thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart.toLongString();
    }

    pointcut doPointcut(): within(tasks..*) &&  execution(* *(..));

    after() : doPointcut(){
        if(enclosedJP.equals(thisJoinPointStaticPart.toLongString()))
            Item.unregisterAll();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps what you need.